# Mongo-Kafka Source Connector can't resume change stream

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am using [Mongo-Kafka](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/master/kafka-source/) to create a source connector. (Version: mongo-kafka-1.0.1-all.jar)

But I got the logs:

```
[2020-05-28 06:28:03,425] INFO Watching for collection changes on 'MyDatabaseName.CollectionName' (com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask)
[2020-05-28 06:28:03,427] INFO New change stream cursor created without offset (com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask)
[2020-05-28 06:28:03,539] INFO Failed to resume change stream: The featureCompatibilityVersion must be 3.6 to use the $changeStream stage. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-feature-compatibility. 72 (com.mongodb.kafka.connect.source.MongoSourceTask)
```

The log shows that it failed to resume change stream.

But my mongodb version is 3.6.6

The post content shows as below:

```
{
   "name": "mongo-source1",                                                       
   "config": {
         "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",      
         "tasks.max":"1",                                                        
         "topics":"test-topic2",
         "connection.uri":"MyMongoURI",
         "database":"MyDatabaseName",                      
         "collection":"CollectionName",  
         "change.stream.full.document": "",
         "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is featureCompatibilityVersion on each node in the deployment?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The featureCompatibilityVersion is 4.0, but the version is 3.6.6. Is this correct?

Comment: That is quite strange, I don't think it is possible to have fcv exceed server version.